# how to compute percentage of high blood pressure people, categorized based on BMI?

Tags: r, percentage

I have a variable with 4 categories, `underweight`, `normal`, `overweight` and `obese`, and I would like to calculate the high pressure %, out of total, for each category.

This is what I tried, but without success:

```
brfss2013 %>%
  group_by(X_bmi5cat) %>%
  filter(!is.na(X_bmi5cat), !is.na(bphigh4)) %>%
  summarise(bph_rate = sum (bphigh4 == "yes") / n())
```

regardless of using round, *100

Can you please help?

Comment: can you provide some example data?

Comment: data.frame': 491775 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ X_bmi5cat: Factor w/ 4 levels "Underweight",..: 4 1 3 2 4 4 2 NA 4 3 ...
 $ bphigh4  : Factor w/ 4 levels "Yes","Yes, but female told only during pregnancy",..: 1 3 3 3 1 1 1 1 3 3 ...

Comment: Please edit your question to add that. It would also help if you explained what "without success" meant. Are results wrong? Do you get an error message?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the % of patients with high blood pressure in each BMI group here is the code to do that

```
library(dplyr)
bmi <- data.frame(bmi = c(rep('uw',5),rep('norm',5), rep('over',5),rep('obese',5)),
                  hpb = rbinom(20,1,.5) , stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

bmi2 <- bmi %>%
  group_by(bmi, hpb) %>%
  tally %>% 
  group_by(bmi) %>% 
 mutate(pct= n/ sum(n))
```

If you want the overall % of patients with high blood pressure here is the code:

```
bmi2 <- bmi %>%
  group_by(bmi, hpb) %>%
  tally %>% 
  ungroup %>% 
 mutate(pct= n/ sum(n))
```

In your code above you try to divide by `n()` but if you want to use your code maybe replace `n()` with just the variable `n`.

Comment: Thanks Mike, I tried replacing the n(), but than it is error for : Evaluation error: non-numeric argument to binary operator.,

Comment: Does the code I provide give you the answer you would like?

Comment: no, in fact did not, but used : sasth1 <- brfss2013 %>%
group_by(X_bmi5cat) %>%
 select(X_bmi5cat,bphigh4)%>%
 table()
sasth1
round(prop.table(sasth1)*100,2)
And this worked. I hope the values are correct. :-) Thanks!